# Why does a task still exist after pressing the back button?

Tags: android, back-stack

[The Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) say

> If the user continues to press Back, then each activity in the stack is popped off to reveal the previous one, until the user returns to the Home screen (or to whichever activity was running when the task began). When all activities are removed from the stack, the task **no longer exists**.

Well I tried this on a galaxy s4 with android 4.3, but afterwards when I hold the home button to show all tasks the task is still there (tried with settings app, help app, internet app, my own app). In what way does it not exist?

Edit:
I'm reading up on tasks to understand the Android system. I have no specific app development problem.

Comment: Holding Home button will display recent apps, It does not meaning that your app is running, In android user, almost never able to stop application, Android OS will decide when to kill that process.

Comment: Do you mean you are not able to see your application in taskmanager by pressing the home button???

Comment: @KPBird That's interesting. However, your answer implies that a task cannot survive its associated process. Do you have a source for this? If the system kills a process with an existing task in it, it is not unreasonable to think that the system might save the task and its back stack and reload it later when the app is relaunched (just a thought).